# Plotting Distance Constrained Points on a Plane

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, embedding, cartesian-coordinates

I'm crossposting this from the mathematics stack exchange at the suggestion of one user who thought somebody here with experience in embedding algorithms might be able to help, though it should be noted that I'm not trying to do a strict graph embedding (which would not allow for vertices to intersect).

Does anybody know of some algorithmic way to tell if it is possible to plot a set of distance constrained points on a cartesian plane. Or, better still, a method to determine the minimum number of dimensions required to accurately depict the points.

As an example: If you have three points and a constraint that says they are all one unit away from each other, you can plot this easily on a cartesian plane as an equilateral triangle.

However, if you have the constraints A->B = 1, A->C = 1, and B->C = 3 then you will not be able to plot these points while maintaining their distances.

However in my case I have a graph with many more than three vertices. The graph is definitely non-planar: one such case involves 1407 vertices all of which are connected by a weighted bidirectional edge that defines the "distance" between the two vertices.

The question is, is there some way to tell if I can depict this graph with accurate distances on a cartesian plane. I know I can't depict it without edges crossing, but I don't care about doing that. I just want the points on the plane an appropriate distance from each other.

Additional information about the graph in case it helps:

1) Each node represents a set of points. 2) The edge weights are derived by optimally overlaying the point sets from each pair of nodes and then taking the RMSD of the resulting point sets. 3) The sets of points represented by any two nodes can be paired with each other. That is, we can think of each node as a set of 8 points numbered 1-8. This numbering is static. When I overlay node A and node B, the points are numbered identically to when I overlay A and C and B and C.

My thoughts: Because RMSD is a metric on R^3 (At least I believe so. This paper claims to prove it http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1107/S0108767397010325/abstract), it should be possible for me to do this in R^3 at the very least.

As my real goal here is to turn this set of points into a nice figure, a three dimensional depiction would actually suffice, as I could depict the 3D figure in 2D. I also recognize that numerical instability in the particular optimal overlay algorithm I'm using will cause issues, but I'm interested in the answer for an ideal case.

Comment: Use a Force Directed Graph algorithm then test the final equilibrium for accuracy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing  wikipedia also mentions using Kamada–Kawai and Fruchterman–Reingold to get results closer to the global minimum.

Comment: Are you looking for [Multidimensional Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)?

Comment: I think I might indeed be looking for Multidimensional Scaling @mhum. Thanks.